# pymongo error document must be an instance of dict

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

i am trying to put an object in a collection but i receive the error saying:

```
raise TypeError("%s must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, "
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

My code looks like this:

```
class DataBase:

    def __init__(self):
        self.myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27018/")
        self.mydb = self.myclient["MMA_TOURNAMNET"]
        self.tournamnets = self.mydb["tournamnets"]

    def insert_new_tournamnet(self, tournament):
        jason_tour = json.dumps(tournament.__dict__)
        print(jason_tour)
        self.tournamnets.insert_one(jason_tour)
```

and i call a function of this class like: `self.data_base.insert_new_tournamnet(tour)`

The form of the tour object after the transformation is:

```
{"list_fighters": [{"Name": "Barry Boday", "Test Status": 0, "Weeks in Bubble": 0}, {"Name": "Steve Vaughn", "Test Status": 0, "Weeks in Bubble": 0}, {"Name": "Jack Zink", "Test Status": 1, "Weeks in Bubble": 0}], "schedule_list": [[{"Name": "Barry Boday", "Test Status": 0, "Weeks in Bubble": 0}, {"Name": "Steve Vaughn", "Test Status": 0, "Weeks in Bubble": 0}]]}
```

Seems good as a Json format to be put in the collection. But i can t get rid of the error. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need serialize object to json, just pass the dict

Answer (score 2):

Just leave your record as a dict and pass that to `insert_one()`:

```
def insert_new_tournamnet(self, tournament):
    self.tournamnets.insert_one(tournament.__dict__)
```