# Nested classes in Python gives: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument

Tags: python, json, mongodb, class

I'm trying to figure out how to serialise this data for MongoDB (using PyMongo).

I have created a toJSON() method in the Categories class, which prints out proper looking JSON but it won't save to MongoDB using insertOne()

```
class Categories:

    def __init__(self, store_key):
        self.store_key = store_key
        self.categories = list() #the items here are Category() objects

    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

The 'has a' class

```
class Category:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.key = ''
        self.subcategories = []
```

The JSON looks good:

```
{"categories": [
    {
        "key": "cosmetics",
        "name": "Cosmetics",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "Face": "face"
            },
            {
                "Eyes": "eyes"
            },
            {
                "Lips": "lips"
            },
            {
                "Cheeks": "cheeks"
            },
            {
                "Nails": "nails"
            },
            {
                "Cosmetic Accessories": "cosmetic-accessories"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "hair",
        "name": "Hair",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "Shampoo & Conditioner": "shampoo--conditioner"
            },
            {
                "Dry Shampoo": "dry-shampoo"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "skincare",
        "name": "Skincare",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "Face Care": "face-care"
            },
            {
                "Sun & Tanning": "sun--tanning"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"store_key": "southdomainpharmacy"}
```

But when  I try to save it doesn't work. I have read that it won't work for classes that contain another class. What is the reason for this, can it be done, or do I have to use a different approach?

I just want to get this data into Mongo without losing the structure, is this possibile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pymongo error document must be an instance of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66768468/pymongo-error-document-must-be-an-instance-of-dict)

Comment: Sort of, I removed the nested class and used a complex list(dict(...)) structure

Answer (score 0):

To store data in MongoDB using pymongo and `insert_one()`, you must pass a dictionary. You don't need to convert anything to a string to make it look like JSON, you just need a dictionary.

You cannot store ad-hoc class objects in MongoDB either, you must convert them to a [type that pymongo understands](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html).

Therefore create a class method that creates a dictionary from your type, and use that to pass to `insert_one()`.

Alternatively take a look at https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/custom_type.html